# Two README files, Doxygen picks the wrong one

Tags: doxygen, readme, doxygen-wizard

Project structure:

```
Project root
   Doxyfile1
   Doxyfile2
   README.md
   Subdir
       README.md
```

`Doxyfile1` is for internal documentation, `Doxyfile2` if for end-user documentation.
`Doxyfile1` documents the whole project, `Doxyfile2` documents `Subdir` only.

In the end-user documentation, I correctly get the `Subdir/README.md` file shown. 
In the internal documentation, I still get the same `Subdir/README.md` file shown, instead of `README.md`.

In the Doxyfiles, I explicitly specified the paths of the `README.md` files, both in the `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` field and in the `INPUT` field.

Why `Doxyfile1` keeps pointing to the wrong `README.md` file?

Could it be that a single `README.md` file is expected in a project, and so a random one is picked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed moving the subproject's Doxyfile in its own directory:

```
Project root
   Doxyfile1
   README.md
   Subdir
       Doxyfile2
       README.md
```

Comment: Just a small question did you have also the RECURSIVE flag on ? as this might explain something as well.

Comment: Yes, the RECURSIVE flags are on for both doxyfiles.